# why if $h \in H - (Z(G) \cap H)$ then we have$ |C_G(h)| \ge |Z(G) \cap H| +|Z(G) \cap H| $?

Tags: abstract-algebra

let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $ \frac{H} {Z(G)\cap H} \cong Z_2 $ and $ [G:H] = n$ .

why if $h \in H - (Z(G) \cap H)$ then we have$ |C_G(h)| \ge |Z(G) \cap H| +|Z(G) \cap H| $ ?

Comment: Are the two terms on the right hand side of the inequality intentionally the same?

Answer (score 0):

Think about both cosets of $Z(G)\cap H$ in $H$.

One of them is $Z(G)\cap H$, which is contained in the centralizer of $h$.

The other coset is $h(Z(G)\cap H)$, which also is contained in $C_G(h)$.

Comment: why Z(G) ∩  H and h(Z(G) ∩  H) are contained in  C(h)? and why |Z(G) ∩  H | + |h(Z(G) ∩  H) | = 2 |Z(G) ∩  H |?

Comment: Q1: h commutes with itself as does everything in $Z(G)\cap H$, and $C_G(h)$ is a subgroup. Q2: Every coset of a subgroup has the same cardinality.